# Dynamic return values with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

One typically defines return values for a Mockito mock during compile time, i.e. statically:

```java
MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
when(myClass.myMethod()).thenReturn(0, 100, 200, ...);
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically by supplying a seed and a function, e.g.:

```java
when(mock.myMethod()).thenReturn(seed, previousVal -> previousVal + 100);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can return an `org.mockito.stubbing.Answer`.

```
class AddingAnswer implements Answer {
    int current = 0;
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        int result = current;
        current += 100;
        return result;
    }
}
```

which you can then wire to your mock like this

```
Answer answer = new AddingAnswer();
when(myClass.myMethod()).then(answer);
```

Or in the generic version you want

```
class DynamicAnswer<T> implements Answer {
    T currentValue;
    UnaryOperator<T> adjustment;
    public DynamicAnswer(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> ad) {
        currentValue = seed;
        adjustment = ad;
    }
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        T result = currentValue;
        currentValue = adjustment.apply(currentValue);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way may be to combine Mockitos Answer with lambdas, streams and iterators. The resulting code is

```
Iterator<Integer> values = Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 100).iterator();
when(myClass.myMethod()).thenAnswer(i -> values.next());
```

The code can be made a little more efficient if you use an IntStream and a PrimitiveIterator.OfInt as the iterator type, but that is probably overkill for a unit test...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `thenAnswer()` as described on mockitos web site.

```
when(mock.myMethod()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Integer>(){
        private final int seed=100;
        private int previousVal=0;
        public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            int currentVal= previousVal;
            previousVal += seed;
            return currentVal;
        }
});
```

but usually this requirement arises from a flawed testing approach:

Each method in a unittest class should verify a *single expectation* on the code under test. Therefore there should be no need for such "dynamic" test value generation.

Comment: Who said it's a unit test? And rather than specifying every single return value, I prefer to define a simple supplier in this particular case.