# Replace Mockito's when thenReturn implementation that was previously defined with new implementation

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am adding tests to a large codebase that is similar to this:

```
public class MyTests{
  @Mock
  private DBService dbService;

  @Before
  public void init(){
    Mockito.when(dbService.getFromDb).thenReturn(getReturnResult());
  }
}
```

Where `getReturnResults()` gets the some fake data. In 99% of cases this is the implementation I want, but when testing for exceptions I would like to do something like this:

```
  @Test
  public void useDifferentDBResults(){
    Mockito.when(dbService.getFromDb).thenReturn(getDifferentReturnResult());
    ...
  }
```

Where `getDifferentReturnResult()` gets some different data that will result in an error. I just need to replace the implementation for this one test.

Comment: Maybe you should move ```Mockito.when(dbService.getFromDb).thenReturn(getReturnResult());``` out of the ```init``` method and duplicate it to each test that needs it. Then you are able to define your own ```Mockito.when(dbService.getFromDb).thenReturn(getDifferentReturnResult());``` in your new test method.

Comment: @D.Lawrence I am specifically trying to avoid doing this, if no other options become available I would be doing it this way.

Comment: If you keep the method in the init and define ```Mockito.when(dbService.getFromDb).thenReturn(getDifferentReturnResult())``` in your method, it would mock the second call to the method. I feel that it is not what you are trying to do either.

Comment: @D.Lawrence Unfortunately that would not work for my scenario as I want all the calls to return this different information. It is looking like not using the init would be the easiest.

Comment: I don't have any other solution than the one I mentionned then.

Comment: It is bit hard to understand question here and what you actually want. WOuld it help => 


doReturn(value).when(mock).method(arguments ...);
doThrow(exception).when(mock).method(arguments ...);
doAnswer(answer).when(mock).method(arguments ...);

Comment: One of the problems with Mockito.when is that the argument you pass to it is the expression that you're trying to stub. So when you use Mockito.when twice for the same method call, the second time you use it, you'll actually get the behaviour that you stubbed the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to my mind:

1. Introduce in the same test class a second instance of `DBService` and use it "...when testing for exceptions":

   ```
   @Mock
   private DBService dbService;

   @Mock
   private DBService dbService2;

   @Before
   public void init() {
      Mockito.when(dbService.getFromDb).thenReturn(getReturnResult());
      Mockito.when(dbService2.getFromDb).thenReturn(getDifferentReturnResult());
   }

   ...

   @Test
   public void useDifferentDBResults(){
      // Use dbService2 here
      ...
   }
   ```

or

2. Write a separate test class just for testing for exception(s) and move to that class `useDifferentDBResults()` and the respective test method(s).

Comment: I think using a separate test file is the best way to do this, I am having trouble 
getting dbService2 to be auto-injected over the original dbService.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically provide the result of the mock then you could use the Answer interface of mockito. See this post for more details:

[Dynamic return values with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887470/dynamic-return-values-with-mockito)

Nevertheless I think in tests it is a best practice to repeat yourself in order to make each testmethod more readable. So my advice would be to move the mock initialization to each test method.